qt6apptestqt_debug_metatypes.json: illegal value
EDIT
My CMake file looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(testqt VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(apptestqt
    main.cpp test.cpp test.hpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(apptestqt
    URI testqt
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
set_target_properties(apptestqt PROPERTIES
#    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.apptestqt
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(apptestqt
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS apptestqt
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

ORIGINAL QUESTION
I have simple testing code as follow:
test.hpp
#pragma once
#include <QQmlEngine>

class test_gadget {
    Q_GADGET
    QML_ELEMENT
    Q_PROPERTY(int test MEMBER test)
public:
    int test;
};

class test_object : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
public:
    test_object(const test_gadget&);
private:
    test_gadget gadget;
};

test.cpp
#include <test.hpp>

test_object::test_object(const test_gadget& other) {
    this->gadget = other;
}

main.cpp
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <test.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/testqt/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    test_gadget gadget;
    test_object test_obj(gadget);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("test_obj", &test_obj);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}

However when I try to compile, there were errors:
[  5%] Built target apptestqt_qmlimportscan
[ 10%] Built target apptestqt_tooling
[ 15%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target apptestqt
[ 20%] Built target apptestqt_autogen
[ 25%] Running AUTOMOC file extraction for target apptestqt
[ 25%] Built target apptestqt_automoc_json_extraction
[ 30%] Automatic QML type registration for target apptestqt
Error 5 while parsing C:/Users/USER/source/repos/build-testqt-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/meta_types/qt6apptestqt_debug_metatypes.json: illegal value
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\apptestqt.dir\build.make:88: apptestqt_qmltyperegistrations.cpp] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:97: CMakeFiles/apptestqt.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:135: all] Error 2
13:22:22: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project testqt (kit: Desktop Qt 6.6.0 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Build"

Note: build-testqt-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\meta_types\qt6apptestqt_debug_metatypes.json is empty
How should I fix this?
Qt version: 6.6.0

I added empty brackets {} to the qt6apptestqt2_debug_metatypes.json file and it compiled, with information added in by the compiler.
